# Replace notebook keyboard with a different layout

Tags: laptop, keyboard-layout

I'm from a small country with only 2m residents (Slovenia) and with few specific characters and accents in our keyboard layout (we share the same layout with Croatia even though our alphabets differ a little). Now when I want to buy a new notebook computer I have to pay a bit higher price because I have to by it from our country's dealers that provide them with locale specific keyboard layout. **And I hate to pay more than I should just because of suitable keyboard.**

This is the standard layout we're using:
[image: Slovenian keyboard layout]

I wonder if it's possible to buy physical notebook replacement keyboards with country-specific layouts? This would give me the possibility to buy my notebook anywhere I can get it for less and just swap that keyboard with what I require.

I'm most interested if brands like ASUS, Lenovo or HP provide this kind of service?

> ***Note***: Our dealers import these notebooks with specific keyboard layout already in place. No changes are being made by them which means that these keyboards could potentially be available from the manufacturer.

Comment: Could you provide the country's name and what is the alphabet you're using called?

Comment: @Darius: I've edited to add my country name and the image of our standard layout with specific characters and added accents (by using **AltGr** key)

Comment: Well, in this case it is a QWERTZ keyboard layout and I was able to find few options of a USB QWERTZ keyboards and their price range between 30-180$.

Comment: @Darius: It's not about USB keyboards. This is about notebook replacement keyboards that you replace directly on the notebook. Can you still provide your search source? Because QWERTZ may not be enough. In Europe there are numerous countries with QWERTZ sequence but different layout.

Comment: One of the searches I did was on Ebay for QWERTZ keyboard and it display some results but as Brian stated you will need a part number to find exactly what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Certainly Lenovo make a wide range of keyboards for their notebooks. The Hardware Maintenance Manual for each model should be available on the support Web site, including a list of part numbers for all the available keyboards as well as instructions how to remove and install them.

Here, for example, is a list of the 38 keyboards available for the ThinkPad T410 I’m typing this on: http://support.lenovo.com/gb/en/documents/migr-74569.

Armed with the OEM part number, you can search for a supplier selling what you need. Since OEMs don’t make all parts available in all markets, you may need to seek alternative supply routes. Your favourite online auction site could be a good starting point – they often have sellers specialising in notebook components (even if the provenance of those items may in some cases be questionable).

I can’t comment on other brands as I’ve no experience with them – but I’d expect any large manufacturer selling computers all over the world to have all the appropriate localised keyboards available.